# adding textView as a subview of a view and adding this view to video

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working in an application in which i am dealing with video . In this application i want to add the text with the video by using the `UITextView`.For this i have created the `UITextView` programmatically and added it as a subview of the `UIView` like this.

```
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

But as soon as i add this view to the video like this--

```
[parentLayer addSublayer:textView];
```

i am getting the error like this--

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1 Address=0x18)

please help me for getting this.Following is code that i have done so far for achieve this.

```
-(void)displayTextInVideo
 {
 if (!self.videoAsset) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Load a Video Asset First"
                                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[self.videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, self.videoAsset.duration)
                               ofTrack:clipVideoTrack
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

[compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[self.videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

CALayer *aLayer = [CALayer layer];
aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30); //Needed for proper display. We are using the app icon (57x57). If you use 0,0 you will not see it
aLayer.opacity = 0.75; //Feel free to alter the alpha here
//Create layer with watermark text instead of image
CGSize videoSize = [self.videoAsset naturalSize];
UITextView *textView =[[UITextView alloc]init];
textView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,282,210);
[textView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];

parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:textView]; //ONLY IF WE ADDED TEXT
//Create composition
AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
videoComp.renderSize = videoSize;
videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
videoComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool      videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
//Create instruction to insert layer
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

NSString *destPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewwatermarkVideo.mp4"];
NSURL *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destPath];



if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destPath])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:destPath error:nil];
}



AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                  presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL=exportUrl;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exporter.videoComposition = videoComp;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
    });
}];
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add UIView subclass as sublayer to layer instanse. Try

```
[parentLayer addSublayer:textView.layer];
```

You are getting bad access because of type mismatch while adding sublayer. The desired type of param is UILayer subclass, but you used UIView instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now , i am getting the error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=0 Address = 0x102006e4) in line :
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));@Doro

Comment: @NehaPurwar your textview does not have a frame. Set frame and try again.

Comment: I thinks you didn't review my code carefully. i have initialised the frame for the text view :   textView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,282,210);

Comment: @NehaPurwar, thanks, i see. Did you try to create separate layer for uitextview and add both to textview.layer and parentLayer? it seems some issue with textview layer

Answer (score 1):

```
 CGSize videoSize; //vedio size goes here

CATextLayer *titleLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
titleLayer.string = @"Text goes here";

titleLayer.fontSize = videoSize.height / 6;

titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
titleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height / 6); //You may need to adjust this for proper display
```

Add this title layer to `parentLayer`.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for answering , but i want to add the text through the textview over the video . And i have done through CATextLayer previously.

Comment: Why textview only? CATextLayer is quite easy and reliable !

Comment: I know that CATextLayer is more reliable than TextView but in this text view i want to perform some operation like scaling , rotation ,etc by using GestureRecognizer.